# Generating power of a vector and putting it in a matrix in numpy in a succint way

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a function which takes in  a numpy array (whichever is more convenient) and a number.

The function should return a matrix of this powers from 0 to n.

e.g. if I input [1,2] and 3, the matrix should return

np.matrix([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 8]])

I know I can write a loop to do this, but is there a more succinct / fast method? Is there way of writing this using generators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `broadcasting` -

```
In [60]: [1,2]**np.arange(4)[:,None]
Out[60]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 8]])
```

More compact one with [`np.vander`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html) as this is basically a `vandermode` matrix -

```
In [78]: np.vander([1,2],4,1).T
Out[78]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 8]])
```

For `matrix` type -

```
In [61]: np.asmatrix([1,2]**np.arange(4)[:,None])
Out[61]: 
matrix([[1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 4],
        [1, 8]])
```

Comment: jeeze, that is so neat!